# How to manually focus/highlight an item in jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI 1.10.2 and I would like to manually highlight/focus an item in the list. Basically, I am trying to achieve a HTML select-like behavior:

- All the results from source should always be shown
- When typing in the inout field, the best match should be highlighted, the list should NOT be filtered
- When the user selects an item, the suggestion list is closed. When the user focuses on the input, the suggestion list should be opened and the selected value should be highlighted.

I can successfully open the suggestion list on input focus and not filter the result list, but I am having a bit of hard time figuring out how to manually highlight/focus the selected element when autocomplete suggestion list is opened and while typing - I am able to find the matching item, but don't know how to "activate" it.

I have tried this:

```
open: function() {
  // Find the selected menu item...
  var $menuEl = ...
  $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.focus(new $.Event("mouseover"), $menuEl );
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that passing `null` instead of an event makes it work:

```
$(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.focus(null, $menuEl );
```

FWIW: I created the Event because an older version of jQuery UI Menu required it. It seems that the UI Menu has changed considerably since then.